# Cypress - How to validate following element

Tags: cypress

`<button _ngcontent-hth-c126="" class="btn btn-secondary grid-btn m-l-12 m-r-8 p-3 warn" disabled>Edit </button>`

I want to validate that element contain 'disabled' or not

how to do that in cypress

Answer (score 2):

You can also validate that it has the disabled attribute like this

```js
cy.get('button').contains('Edit').should('have.attr', 'disabled')
```

Ref [Method and Value](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Method-and-Value)

Also, inside the selector. This command specifies everything - both element identity and disabled condition.

```js
cy.contains('button:disabled', 'Edit')
```

Answer (score 1):

To assert that the button is disabled:

```js
cy.contains('button', 'Edit').should('be.disabled')
```

To assert that the button is not disabled:

```js
cy.contains('button', 'Edit').should('not.be.disabled')
```